# Crash iterating through an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to simply print out the contents of an array.

```
//initialization, ...

    NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@[stock1,stock2,stock3], nil];

    for (BNRStockHolding *stock in stockprices) {
//            says that there are 3 objects in stock and crashes.
//            tried to check -> isMemberOfClass:BNRStockHolding in an if before and got 'unexpected interface name'.
        NSLog(@"Purchase Price: %.02f \n Shares: %d \n Current Price: %.02f \n \n \n \n", [stock purchasePrice], [stock numberOfShares],[stock currentSharePrice]);
```

Comment: You are creating a `NSArray` with a `NSArray`, not 'stockprices' see @mixel's solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@[stock1, stock2, stock3], nil];
//is same as
NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:stock1, stock2, stock3, nil], nil];
//or
NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stock1, stock2, stock3, nil], nil];
```

So, you're basically creating an array whose 0th element is an array because `@[stock1,stock2,stock3]` itself creates an array.

---

Instead do:

```
NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stock1, stock2, stock3, nil];
```

or

```
NSArray *stockprices = @[stock1,stock2,stock3];
```

Comment: Maybe explain the difference? That would be more useful than just saying 'replace your code with this code'.

Comment: @[stock1, stock2, stock3] already creates an array. He wrote, that it is the same as [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stock1, stock2, stock3, nil]. @[] is the new Objective-C literal for NSArrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating here an array of array with your code code:

```
 NSArray *stockprices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@[stock1,stock2,stock3], nil];
```

You can simply write :

```
NSArray *stockprices = @[stock1,stock2,stock3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using array within array; Parent Array has one object and child array has three stock objects. If you will get [parentArray objectAtIndex:0]; it will work OK; But if you will do [parentArray objectAtIndex:1]; App will crash because, parent array just have one object.
It may help you to investigate problem.